# How to add my voice with background mp3 music in android?

Tags: android

I am creating an app, which is based on music composition. In this App, a .mp3 song is playing in the background and the user can add their voice with this music and save the recorded music file. I am using `media recorder` and `media player` for recording and playing, but my recorded file is not suitable for my app.

Answer (score 0):

The `android.media.MediaPlayer` class is used to control the audio or video files.

`MediaRecorder` class can be used to record audio and video files.

You can set output format like this...here `3gp` example i am giving you

```
Mediarecorder recorder;
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
```

Comment: i am also used those classes but when i record my voice with head phone with background music than my recorded voice is larger instead of my background music.